# CRM 2013: Error Custom Workflow Assembly Profiler

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, workflow-activity

I'm trying to debug my custom workflow assembly using the plugin registration tool for the first time. We are using CRM 2013 on-premise version.

However in setting up the profiler, I got this error below about my mismatched version of 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow'.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)........................

I see that my Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow version in the reference property is actually 5.0.0.0. However when I delete and re-add the reference (from the CRM 2013 SDK), then it shows a different version 5.0.9690.3739.

I read other questions about this, but I don't exactly understand how to synch the correct version together. Could someone please let me know how to do this step-by-step - if I need to change the one on the CRM server.

[image: Reference property]

Notice the difference version between the two pics.

[image: Re-adding the reference]

Comment: The v5.x.x.x DLLs are the 2011 DLL files, not the 2013 DLL files. The 2013 DLL files all are v6.x.x.x. It seems like you have the 2011 SDK, not the 2013 SDK.

Comment: Funny, the CRM 2013 SDK contains the version 5.x.x.x dll. How can I find the version 6?

Comment: Did you download the CRM 2013 SDK from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321. I'm looking at it on my screen in VS and I see the Version property for  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow as 6.0.0.0.

Comment: Ok I have updated to use Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow version 6.0.0.0, but I'm still getting the error when trying to use the Profile Workflow. I'm able to update my plugin just find though.